# Pip freeze generating '@ file:///' on conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

First time this is happening to me, and I have no idea why pip is outputting the requirements in such strange form. I'm using a conda environment. Output example from `pip freeze`:

```
aioredis @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/aioredis_1591809643295/work
amqp @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/amqp_1591005859311/work
asgiref==3.2.7
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
```

Why aren't `aioredis` and `amqp` listed with their respective version just like the other requirements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589814/7976758

Comment: @phd I saw this, but it doesn't solve my problem, as I need to pass the requirements to a different machine. How can I force it to have the version?

Answer (score 53):

This solves it:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This is universal: it prints also packages installed with conda and by pip from both PyPI and Github.

Comment: This works, but can you explain why the other doesn't?

Comment: This works as long as there is no [pip package installed from a VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/1256347). For those packages the `pip freeze` command does show the correct output. Do you know how to combine the best of `--format freeze` and `pip freeze`?